# Calendar function to also stop at the end of the month

Tags: python

I have this python function:

```
import datetime
def date_by_adding_business_days(from_date, add_days,holidays):
    business_days_to_add = add_days
    current_date = from_date
    while business_days_to_add > 0:
        current_date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        weekday = current_date.weekday()
        if weekday >= 5:
            continue
        if current_date in holidays:
            continue
        business_days_to_add -= 1
    return current_date
Holidays =[datetime.datetime(2015,10,3),datetime.datetime(2015,10,4)]
print date_by_adding_business_days(datetime.date(2015,10,23), 6,Holidays)
```

This will output:

```
2015-11-02
```

What I want is to make a change that output date will stop at the end of the month, for my example I would need to output 2015-10-30. For any given date I don't want the output outside of the given date month. If I would have lets say: datetime.date(2015,10,29) and I want to add 5 days, this should output 2015-10-30 (only add 1 day) and so on. Holidays(marked in my list) and weekends aren't counted.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: what's is your problem?

Comment: From my post : ''What I want is to make a change that output date will stop at the end of the month''

Comment: You mean it will run from 02 - 30?

Comment: 1-30 if my input date would be in October

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`calendar.monthrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange) which returns tuple `(first weekday of month, days in month)` to figure out how many days there are in given month:

```
>>> import calendar
>>> calendar.monthrange(2015, 10)
(3, 31)
```

Then you can change your function to store the potential result every time the end of loop is being reached. On top of that you need to change the type of `holidays` to `date` instead of `datetime` since they are different objects:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 17) == datetime.date(2016, 11, 17)
False
```

With above changes the end result would look something like this:

```
import datetime
import calendar

def date_by_adding_business_days(from_date, add_days,holidays):
    business_days_to_add = add_days
    current_date = from_date
    result = None
    _, days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(current_date.year, current_date.month)
    while business_days_to_add > 0 and current_date.day < days_in_month:
        current_date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        weekday = current_date.weekday()
        if weekday >= 5:
            continue
        if current_date in holidays:
            continue
        business_days_to_add -= 1
        result = current_date
    return result
Holidays =[datetime.date(2015,10,3),datetime.date(2015,10,4)]
print date_by_adding_business_days(datetime.date(2015,10,23), 6,Holidays)
```

Output:

```
2015-10-30
```

Comment: I wont work only with 1 month, I need a range on all year, the dates I will apply my function will be random ones, I can have a date in June for example and so on.

Comment: And also the output 2015-10-31 is on a weekend, weekends don't count! We can't have a output in a weekend or holyday.

Comment: @AnakinVader Fixed the issue with weekend. What's the expected output in case that you pass `(2015, 10, 31)` which is Saturday as `from_date`? Based on the question holiday or weekend shouldn't be returned but the return date shouldn't be in following month either.

Comment: I won't have any day on Saturday nor Sunday nor in holyday, this will be a working days.

Comment: And yes, don't count the weekend and holiday, start day wont be weekend and holiday, but when is the case to get out of month, stop at the last days that isnt a holiday or weekend.

Comment: @AnakinVader: For me it seems to work fine for June, if I use `datetime.date(2015,6,19), 1, []` as parameters the result is `2015-06-22` which is expected as 19th of June 2015 was Friday. If you still encounter issues could you provide the input and expected output?

Comment: I will test this right now, thanks a lot, I will be back with a feedback.

Comment: The only thing right now is this function will count the holidays now, for exampe for this : Holidays =[datetime.datetime(2015,12,15),datetime.datetime(2015,10,4)]
print date_by_adding_business_days(datetime.date(2015,12,11), 3,Holidays) ---> the output will be 2015-12-16 and it should be 2015-12-17, cause I marked (2015,12,15) as a holiday.

Comment: @AnakinVader Got it, holidays were type of `datetime.datetime` and `from_date` is `datetime.date` so comparing them didn't work as expected. Changed the answer, now it should finally work.